# multiple drag&drop function does not work

Tags: javascript, salesforce, jstree, jstree-dnd

I'm using jstree functions and can do Drag&Drop nodes from one side to other side. But if I try to select multiple nodes(more than one) and drag&drop them to other side some of them are copied but some of them not copied. For example, I selected 4 nodes to copy, but it copied just 2 nodes. Please help.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I use default jstree methods as a static resources. Do you have any idea about multiple clone on jstree?